# Fixed background image scroll on mobile touch devices doesn't update right away

Tags: android, css, scroll, touch, background-image

CSS:

```
body{
margin:0 auto;
background-image:url("someURL"),
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

This works fine in modern browsers, the image stays the same when scrolling. On an android tablet however the image doesn't update right away. The image only updates about half a second after you release (move your finger away) and in the mean while the gap is just white.

Is there away to fix this issue or is it just how certain browsers behave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is known bug, you can find details here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301

Comment: Yes, but only a bug in Android's native browser?